# Making css 3d responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

Aloha,

Here is the code I want to use for my project.
http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/examples/carousel-02-dynamic.html
3D transforms by DeSandro.

My task is to make it close to fullscreen (for example for 1024x768 like 900x700) and make it resnponsive.

Questions would be:

1) Can it be done with bootstrap? I tried Bootstrap container/row/span but all of them just screw everything.

2) http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ I found this media queries. Are they enough for make it responsive? or there is never enough?

i tried to copy code to http://jsfiddle.net/ but it doesnot work there I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from your description its clear that you want a Jquery 3d responsive carousel...
So why using with bootstrap its of no use... Just attach a jquery plugin for your requirement..

Check out this plugin...

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/51/

The responsive part here can be done by the use of media queries and their are many examples too you can choose from it...

Comment: the thing is that I'm not going to use images on those slides. I want to show google maps on every slide

Comment: if you have little bit of knwledge abt jquery you can convert img tags to divs and embed gmaps in them...